# android parse StarterProject

Tags: android, parse-platform

When I carry out "the parse starter project" on "android studio", I can neither enter data in the "TestObject" class nor create the class itself. I nevertheless followed the explained procedure to create new applications on the site but nothing happened and the online test keeps showing "no data found".

Here is the code I keep carrying out:

Thank you for your help.

**Starter Application**

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, "XXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXX");//here i put my keys
        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
        // Optionally enable public read access.
        // defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
}
```

**MainActivity  :**

```
ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
    testObject.put("foo", "bar");

    testObject.saveInBackground();
```

Comment: Do you have any errors? exceptions?

Comment: I just started too everything looks fine, check your permissions and check core page. I had default TestObject Class with foo column. Maybe parse creates it when you click test at guide page.
Edit: If you create TestObject class manuelly, dont forget to add "foo" column.

Comment: Sometimes it takes a page refresh on the Data Viewer of parse.com to see the new classes

Comment: Also I found out that if you created this object table before and try to add new rows of different column types the save will fail too. The column takes the type of the data that was first submitted to it, so if your first "foo" data item was not a string value like "bar", the new row would not get added.

Comment: I don't have any exception or error message. I don't understand why other people in my team with the same code and having created the same kind of account succeeds. Is there any limitation with accounts from the same domain  or with requests sent from similar ips range?

Answer (score 0):

### Dis you add ---in data table of your parse?

Please you add class 'TestObject' to parse.com

Comment: You do not have to manually add the class to your parse.com dashboard actually, once you do `saveInBackground()` it gets created.